# Unit test a callback

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to write unit tests for a Presenter in my application and I have the following use case, for which I don't know how I should go about writing a Unit test.

```
interface ICallback
{
    void onConfirm(String str);
}

interface IPopup
{
    void show(ICallback callback);
}

class Presenter
{
    private IPopup m_popup;
    private String m_result;

    Presenter(IPopup popup)
    {
        m_popup = popup;
    }

    public String getResult() { return m_result; }

    void onClick()
    {
        m_popup.show(new ICallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onConfirm(String str)
            {
                m_result = str;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The function `show` creates a `PopupWindow` that has an OK button whose `onClick` method calls `ICallback.onConfirm`.

I would like to test what happens inside `onConfirm()`, but I have no idea how to go about it. How does one do this? Or should I structure my code differently so it will more test friendly?

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and mark as self-answered :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Found a solution**

I used `ArguementCaptor` to capture the callback and then called the `onConfirm` method of the callback and verified if it did it's job.

```
@Mock IPopup m_popup;

@Test
public void callbackTest()
{
    String str = "test";
    ArgumentCaptor<ICallback> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ICallback.class);

    m_presenter.onClick();
    verify(m_popup).show(argument.capture());

    argument.getValue().onConfirm(str);
    assertEquals(str, m_presenter.getResult());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good case for [Mockito's](http://site.mockito.org/) verify() method. No time to post a proper example at the moment, but have a look at this post:

[Mockito - what does verify method do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27457044/mockito-what-does-verify-method-do)

[See also](http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify)

Basically you need to mock an instance of ICallback in your test, and after the point where the OK button is clicked, call `verify()` against your `onConfirm()` method. (I'm assuming you're using Espresso for your UI-side unit tests)

Comment: Thank you. I actually found a solution using ``ArgumentCaptor` and calling the `onConfirm()` method of the callback and then verifying the the result. I can post the code after new years for future readers.

Mocking `ICallback` was not an option, since it is not injected into the presenter. The presenter creates the callbacks inline when it calls the `show()` method.